# Trouble registering a twitter webhook due to invalid CRC

Tags: node.js, twitter, webhooks

I am having trouble registering my twitter webhook.  I am using twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard, and although the request is reaching the webhook (I can see it in the logs), I keep getting this return:

**Webhook URL does not meet the requirements. Invalid CRC token or json response format.**

I believe that I have followed the description here pretty carefully:
https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard

My credentials are correct, permissions are correct, and I've set up an environment.

Server side is in node.js.  The simple code to respond to the webhook creation request is here.

I'm using the crypto library to create the hmac (again, as in the example provided in the link above.)

```
function twitterWebhook(req, res, next)
{
my.logger.verbose('Entered the Twitter Webhook');
my.logger.verbose('Here is the url: ' + JSON.stringify(req.url));
my.logger.verbose('Here is the query: ' + JSON.stringify(req.query));

var crc_token = req.query.crc_token;

my.logger.verbose('crc_token is:  ' + crc_token);
my.logger.verbose('secret is   :  ' + conf.T_consumer_secret);

var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 
conf.T_consumer_secret).update(crc_token).digest('base64');
my.logger.verbose('hmac is     :  ' + hmac);

if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'){
    var aResponse = {response_token:hmac};
    var aResponseString = JSON.stringify(aResponse);
    res.send(hmac);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Leigh have you got any solution for it because I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
response_token: 'sha256=' + hmac
```

You have to add `sha256=` in the start of the response token, had same issue got fixed after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python3.7 + ngrok for my callbakurl and nodejs service provided by Twitter to manage callbackurl, subscriptions.

1. Find the nodejs here: [Official Twitter Account Activity Dashboard](https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard)

2. Here's my flask webhook exposed via ngrok

   ```
   @app.route('/webhook/twitter', methods=['GET'])
   def webhook_challenge():
       # creates HMAC SHA-256 hash from incoming token and your consumer secret
       sha256_hash_digest = hmac.new(API_KEY_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), msg=request.args.get('crc_token').encode('utf-8'),                                  digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

       # construct response data with base64 encoded hash
       response = {'response_token': 'sha256=' + base64.b64encode(sha256_hash_digest).decode('utf-8')}

       # returns properly formatted json response
       return json.dumps(response)
   ```

> It's important to note that after you set app your Twitter Account API Dashboard, go ahead and regenerate the keys yet again.
>
> Since you will have two applications running, for my case it was the Flask app and the NodeJs App, ensure you update all Consume Api Keys, and Access Token in all apps.

Failure to update any will result in an error. In my case, I had not updated the Consumer_Api_Secret on my Flask app and was getting the error **Webhook URL does not meet the requirements. Invalid CRC token or json response format.**

After all this, it is critical to manage your subscriptions.

Twitter Account Dashboard (node.js app) insists that

**Take note of the deployed URL, revisit your developer.twitter.com Apps Settings page, and add the following URL values as whitelisted Callback URLs:**

```
http(s)://your.app.domain/callbacks/addsub

http(s)://your.app.domain/callbacks/removesub
```

1. The **http(s)** can either be HTTP or HTTPS.
2. The **your.app.domain** can either be localhost or [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)
3. Always ensure your callbackurl does not contain any white space either at the beginning or at the end. I cannot stress this enough.